# What does confusion points: matches stand by?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am trying to train utterances and whenever I am giving value to enum type concept it tells me confusion point matches. What does it meany by confusion point matches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ll need a vocab file to back the symbols.

Such as this one. Note that the path is important - make sure it's in your locale.

```
vocab(Planet) {
  "Mercury" { "Mercury" }
  "Venus" { "Venus" }
  "Earth" { "Earth" "The Old Earth" }
  "Mars" { "Mars" "The Red Planet" }
  "Jupiter" { "Jupiter" }
  "Saturn" { "Saturn" }
  "Uranus" { "Uranus" }
  "Neptune" { "Neptune" }
  "Pluto" { "Pluto" }
}
```

here’s the associated enum for that vocab:

```
enum (Planet) {
  description (The resort's affiliated planetary system (include the planet and its moons). Since the list and vocab is exhaustive, we can use an enum.)
  symbol (Mercury)
  symbol (Venus)
  symbol (Earth)
  symbol (Mars)
  symbol (Jupiter)
  symbol (Saturn)
  symbol (Uranus)
  symbol (Neptune)
  symbol (Pluto)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check if you have a vocab file for the enum types. If there is no vocab file, the enums will not be recognized by natural language.